# How to send JSon array to remote asmx webservice using c#?

Tags: c#, json, web-services

In my application i've to send request to a remote asmx web service which is asking for a number of parameters. There is a parameter which is asking for json array. But i can't figure it out that how can i input my json string in the asmx url.(There is no issues with other string values for other parameters).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code are you using now to make calls to this service?

Comment: @BrianRogers I'm using C# to send the request.

Comment: OK, can you edit your question to post the code you are using to make the request currently (without the array)?  It is easier to make an answer if we can see what you're starting from.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that unless the webservice has been heavily customised, you are going to need to pass that parameter in the request body rather than as a GET parameter. For example (with jQuery):

```
var data = {
  paramName: ['this', 'is', 'the', 'array']
};

$.post('service.asmx/Method?getParam1=herp&getParam2=derp', data)
  .done(function(d)
  {
    console.log('Response: ' + JSON.stringify(d));
  });
```

It's been a while since I used an ASMX service, and I'm not 100% positive that you can mix parameters like that. I have a feeling that if you put anything in the body, you have to put everything in it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But is there any way to do this in c# code?

Comment: Sorry for that assumption that you were talking about a JS client; that was dumb. If you're using C#, why not use a Service Reference instead and let it all be handled for you? Or are you doing that, and it's specifically asking for a JSON array? Because that's super weird, and I assume it just wants stringified JSON...?

Comment: I'm using WebRequest to send the request.

Comment: Is there some reason for using a WebRequest instead of a Service Reference?

Comment: Actually, I've joined the project recently, the previous development team used WebRequest to handle Web Service. And now i've instructed to follow the previous structure. This is working with other Web Services. But a particular web service is troubling me. This service needs few string parameters and a json parameter. I've no clue for it. - @Millie